# Optimize query with timestamp index

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

In MySql have a large table `historical_price` with 2 `n:1` relationships to the table `instrument`, a `timestamp` and a `price`:

```
CREATE TABLE `historical_price` 
(  
    `price_nbr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `insid` int(11)  NOT NULL,  
    `curr_insid` int(11) NOT NULL,  
    `timestamp_` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
    `price` float DEFAULT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`price_nbr`),  
    KEY `insid` (`insid`),  
    KEY `curr_insid` (`curr_insid`),  
    KEY `timestamp_` (`timestamp_`),  
    CONSTRAINT ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I want to run many queries like this:

```
SELECT price 
FROM historical_price 
WHERE insid=566 AND curr_insid=2 AND timestamp_ > '2012-05-01'
LIMIT 0,1
```

for getting the older record on that `instrument` that matches the `timestamp` `greater than` condition.

The `explain` output is:

```
id | select_type |      table       | type | possible_keys                | key   | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra 
 1 |   SIMPLE    | historical_price | ref  | insid,curr_insid,timestamp_  | insid |   4     | const | 987190 | Using where
```

Before adding new multi-column indexes, or a new column for helping the db engine, I'd like to ask your opinion about which option could lead to the best results, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add a multi key comprising of `insid,curr_insid,timestamp_`

Comment: Wow! I was expecting that the things were more complicated... it works fine now